Autodesk Construction Cloud API - Update Project
I'm aware now that there is an API Endpoint to create a new Project in ACC (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projects-project-Id-users-POST/)
Is there any resource to update/PATCH an existing Project?
I haven't been able to try any other option as no endpoint is documented to update a project.
Thanks for your help.

As you maybe aware of in the limitation of ACC API Doc, updating the ACC project is current a limitation, it's still working in the progress.
We currently do not provide ACC endpoints for the following operations:

Fetching the status of an asynchronous job while creating a project
or importing multiple project users.
Retrieving ACC project roles. We
recommend using the Data Connector API to fetch project role data.
Updating or deleting ACC projects.


Thanks Zhong. Noted. Please provide any updates when this is allowed.

Are there any plans to add support for renaming / deleting project in the API? It seems like a strange limitation to have.
